# Why can't create new table from `show columns from tablename`?

Tags: mysql

Show all fields from a tablen with :

```
show columns from tablename;
```

I want to store the result in a new table:

```
insert into newtable (show columns from tablename);
```

It can't work,how to create new table from `show columns from tablename`?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Copy an existing table?

Comment: Database administration statements such as SHOW are not SELECT statements. If you want to incorporate dynamically generated column info in your queries then you need to compose a regular SELECT and get the information you want from [information schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-columns-table.html).